# Calculating the required volume of Helium to put in a weather balloon

Tags: ideal-gas, atmospheric-science, gas, buoyancy, adiabatic

**Question**

I am working on a project where we will launch a weather balloon with some scientific instruments tied beneath the balloon. We fill the balloon with helium from tanks of compressed helium. The amount of helium removed from the tanks is measured using a pressure gauge.

How can I calculate how much helium to put in the balloon in order to produce a given lift force when the balloon is released?

**Attempt**

Define the following variables & subscripts:

- $m_h,\rho_h$ mass, density of helium pumped into balloon
- $m_a,\rho_a$ mass, density of air displaced by the helium in the balloon

The buoyant force experienced by the balloon is
\begin{align*}
F_b&=-g(m_h-m_a)\\
&=-g(\rho_hV-\rho_aV)
\end{align*}

The volume required to produce a force $F_b$ is then
$$V=\frac{F_b}{g(\rho_a-\rho_h)}$$

The difficulty I'm having is predicting the density of helium after it has expanded inside the balloon.

1. The process is not adiabatic, because the tank nozzle gets extremely cold and frosts over. As the helium expands, it gets cold and heat travels from the metal walls of the tank nozzle to the gas.
2. The helium pressure is not only equilibrating with the air, it is fighting against the tension of the balloon.

It seems that these two factors would result in a higher density $\rho_h$ than one might predict under adiabatic expansion.

One thought I had was to assume (hopefully with allowable error) that the process is actually adiabatic. Then I could use the adiabatic expansion relations:

\begin{align}
P_2&=P_1(\frac{V_1}{V_2})^{k-1}~~~~~(1)\\
\rho_2&=\rho_1(\frac{P_2}{P_1})^{\frac{1}{k}}~~~~~~~~(2)
\end{align}

Substituting $V_2=\frac{F_b}{g(\rho_a-\rho_2)}$ into (1) and then this expression for $P_2$ into (2) yields an expression that can be solved for $\rho_2$. However something about this doesn't seem correct, if only because it assumes that the helium from one tank will expand to the required volume, which isn't necessarily the case.

Any thoughts, comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the density of the helium at the temperature and pressure of the hight you want to reach (same for the air density). The pressures are equal (I am not sure the tension of the balloon will be significant), and the temperatures too, I am sure they will reach equilibrium soon regardless of the initial temperature of the helium.